# How to properly write to logfile from several python threads at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a multiple threads running, where every thread will write something to the same logfile. How could I do this?

My current solution is `open("log.txt", 'a').write("something\n")` but I don't know whether too many open connections will eventually fail or cause messy output such as

```
something
sosomethingmething
```

or similar. Is there a better way?

Comment: **Don't roll your own logging code.** Use the `logging` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For logging purposes, you can use the logging module. The logging module is thread-safe and will handle the locking for you.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

You can even add `%(threadName)s` to the `logging.Logger` formatting, such that you'll know which thread wrote the given line to the log file. MWE folows:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
stderrHandler = logging.StreamHandler() # Will output to STDERR.
stderrHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
```